# Tkinter MessageBox 'pausing' main GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to show a warning/message box without 'pausing' the window it was called from?

I'm calling a method in another module that checks if an option is present in my .ini file using configparser.
If the option is absent, I am displaying a warning box just to let the user know and then continue on without doing anything special.
While the warning box is displayed, the main window 'pauses' and looses all grid/pack configurations until I close the message box.

Is there a way to achieve this while keeping the background frames looping?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We cannot really help unless we see some code and can test the code by reproducing your problem. Even if messagebox stops the rest of tkinter from performing task (not sure if it does or not) it should not make you lose your geometry management.

Comment: Just create an instance of `Toplevel`, and put anything you want in it.

Comment: I figured someone would ask for a MCVE. I didn't have enough time to try and make one before my work shift ended. My code is so extensive at this point I would have to spend considerable amount of time doing that. But that being said, I think Bryan's suggestion is what I am looking for.... don't know why I didn't think of that in the first place